# How to run docker commands in java 19

Tags: scripts, java, docker

I am trying to run docker commands in java, to create a Dockerfile and create a container out of it. It can be done in another way, but this is what I tried so far:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"cd", "/home/alex/IdeaProjects/test/src/Docker", "&& docker", "build", " -f", "Dockerfile.txt", "-t", "java-app1", "."});
            processBuilder.inheritIO();
            processBuilder.directory(new File("bin"));
            processBuilder.start();
```

This an other way:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cd", "/home/alex/IdeaProjects/test/src/Docker", "&& docker", "build", " -f", "Dockerfile.txt", "-t", "java-app1", "."});
```

Is is possible to create custom containers directly from java?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? That question seems better suited to a Docker or Java forum.

Comment: Hello David, I am using ubuntu 22.04